# Strange Integral $\int_0^ x\dfrac{\frac{t}{t^2+1}-\arctan(t)}{\arctan^2(t)+t^2} \, dt$

Tags: calculus, power-series

This integral baffles me if anyone can help derive it, or demonstrate it, I truly appreciate it.
$$\int_0^ x\frac{\frac{t}{t^2+1}-\arctan(t)}{\arctan^2(t)+t^2} \,dt = \dfrac{\arctan\left(\dfrac{\arctan(x)}{x}\right)-\arctan \left(\dfrac{x}{\arctan(x)}\right)}{2} $$

A theorem? No, ERL.

Comment: This is ill-defined

Comment: what's the variable of integration?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{\frac{x}{1+x^2}-\arctan x}{\arctan x^2 + x^2}
= \frac{x(\arctan x)' - \arctan x}{\arctan x^2 + x^2}
= \frac{ x^2\left(\frac{\arctan x}{x}\right)'}{\arctan x^2 + x^2}
= \cdots
$

Answer (score 2):

Following  achille hui's hint
$$\frac{\frac{x}{1+x^2}-\arctan x}{(\arctan x)^2 + x^2} = \frac{x(\arctan x)' - \arctan x}{(\arctan x)^2 + x^2} = \frac{ x^2\left(\frac{\arctan x}{x}\right)'}{(\arctan x)^2 + x^2} = \frac{ \left(\frac{\arctan x}{x}\right)'}{1+\left(\frac{\arctan x}x\right)^2} $$ which makes $$I=\int\frac{\frac{x}{1+x^2}-\arctan x}{(\arctan x)^2 + x^2}\,dx=\int \frac{ \left(\frac{\arctan x}{x}\right)'}{1+\left(\frac{\arctan x}x\right)^2} \,dx$$ Now, the obvious change of variable $u=\frac{\arctan x}x$ leads to $$I=\int\frac{du}{1+u^2}=\arctan u=\arctan \left(\frac{\arctan x}{x}\right)$$ Then, provided  $t\geq 0$,$$J=\int_0^t\frac{\frac{x}{1+x^2}-\arctan x}{(\arctan x)^2 + x^2}\,dx=\arctan \left(\frac{\arctan (t)}{t}\right)-\frac{\pi }{4}=\frac 12\left( 2\arctan \left(\frac{\arctan t}{t}\right)-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$$ Now, use some classical trigonometric identities to get the rhs.

Comment: Is $arctan(0) / 0=1$?

Comment: @ItachíUchiha. By Taylor $\arctan(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+O\left(x^4\right)$ which makes $\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}=1-\frac{x^2}{3}+O\left(x^3\right)$

Comment: @ItachíUchiha. Your are very welcome !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici:  Thank you kindly.

Comment: @ItachíUchiha: key observation, thank U.